# OS X cd command in /usr/bin instead of /bin

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystem

On OS X 10.8 I was looking at my /bin folder and found that cd was not there, but rather in the /usr/bin folder. Why is that? From the FHS ([Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). I know that /bin should contain essential binaries, i.e. those required when no other filesystems are mounted. Is cd not essential enough? (by the way, it appears the "su" command is also in /usr/bin). Now, I know that OS X doesn't follow strictly the FHS, but is there a reason for these different location of binaries?

Comment: When using acronyms, that may be uncommon to most e.g. FHS ([Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)), consider describing or linking so as those that do not know them off the top of their head aren't totally lost.

Comment: As FHS is Linux why should or does it apply to Unix ?

Comment: @user3439894 sorry, you are totally right. I edited the question.

Comment: @Mark I thought FHS it's more Unix than just Linux

Comment: Wikipedia says  "It is maintained by the Linux Foundation. The latest version is 3.0, released on 3 June 2015. [1] Currently it is only used by Linux distributions."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd` is a shell builtin, and *has* to be a builtin to work. If it were executed as a normal command, it'd run as a subprocess, change that subprocess's directory, and then exit... having no effect at all on the parent shell's directory.

As for `su`: the fondamental distinction between /bin and /usr/bin is that /usr/bin might be on a different filesystem from the root, and hence not be available early in the boot process; thus /bin (and /sbin) must contain all of the commands needed early in the boot process. On OS X, `su` apparently isn't needed during boot.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply! Out of curiosity... `cd` being a shell builtin means that it's code is stored inside /bin/bash executable? (sorry, I do  understand the meaning of your answer, I just don't know how a shell builtin it's implemented)

Comment: @ggrim: I wouldn't say "stored inside" so much as "is part of". I believe it's actually implemented as a function included in the `bash` source code. BTW, it's not just bash -- every shell shell (zsh, dash, etc) has to have `cd` as a builtin, or it'd fail for the reason I gave. You might be interested in [this previous question on the Unix&Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not).

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program/38819#38819) has an interesting historical note about `cd` as a builtin vs. separate program.